# Reading and parsing external XML file in a Jelly Template

Tags: email, jenkins, jelly

I'm using Jenkins 1.410 and Email-Ext 2.14.  My project is a sanity check to verify a number of other builds, ensuring that their artifacts are being delivered properly and then to send out a summary email.  That's all fine.

Now I'm trying to parse the parent project's POM.xml and extract a bunch of dependency versions, and include them in a nicely formatted section in the email.

The Question:  How, in the Jelly template, can I read the external pom.xml (grab it as a collection/array of lines, xml dom object, big string, whatever) and extract the properties/attributes that I need.  Given that, I can format them into a table, or something like that.

Do I need to create my own plugin (that'll be new for me)?  Or does this functionality already exist?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality already exists in Email-ext plugin. You can read XML files from the Jelly script configured in that plugin using xml tag library:  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jelly/libs/xml/tags.html

Below is an example how to parse a pom.xml file located in the jenkins job workspace. Once file is  read to {myxmldoc} it becomes a dom4j document which can be used with standard XPATH expressions to query or loop through needed attributes and elements:

```
<j:set var="WORK_SPACE" value="${buildenv.get('WORKSPACE')}"/>
<x:parse xml="${WORK_SPACE}/pom.xml" var="myxmldoc"/> 

<!--select element with particular attribute-->
<x:set var="myvar" select="$myxmldoc/project/build/plugins/plugin[@attribute='abc']"/>

<!--Loop through elements-->
<x:forEach var="myloopvar" select="$myxmldoc/project/build/plugins/plugin">
.....
</x:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Pre-Steps**

```
1. Download common-jelly package from: http://redrockdigimark.com/apachemirror/commons/jelly/binaries/commons-jelly-1.0.zip
2. Extract the files from the zip
3. Copy the following files: commons-jelly-tags-util-1.1.1.jar, commons-jelly-tags-xml-1.1.jar, commons-jelly-tags-fmt-1.0.jar
4. Paste the above files at: <Jenkins server path>\war\WEB-INF\lib
5. Restart Jenkins
```

**XML IS: abc.xml**

```
<sites>
 <site>
  <URL>http://www.google.com</URL>
  <STATUS>200</STATUS>
 </site>
 <site>
  <URL>http://www.yahoo.com</URL>
  <STATUS>200</STATUS>
 </site>
</sites>
```

**Jelly Code to read above XML**

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:l="/lib/layout" xmlns:t="/lib/hudson" xmlns:f="/lib/form" xmlns:x="jelly:xml" xmlns:html="jelly:html" xmlns:util="jelly:util">

<j:set var="xmlFilePath" value="${build.getWorkspace().child('abc.xml')}"/>
<util:file name="${xmlFilePath}" var="xmlFileContent" />
<x:parse var="myxmldoc" xml="${xmlFileContent}"/>
<x:set var="allSites" select="$myxmldoc/sites"/>
<table class="border">
 <tr>
  <th class="border1"><b>URL</b></th>
  <th class="border1" width="140px"><b>HTTP Code</b></th>
  <th class="border1" width="140px"><b>Status</b></th>
 </tr>
 <x:forEach var="mysite" select="$allSites/site">
 <j:set var="myURL"><x:expr select='$mysite/URL' /></j:set>
 <j:set var="myStatus"><x:expr select='$mysite/STATUS' /></j:set>
 <tr>
  <td class="border_test_passed">
   <a href="${myURL}">${myURL}</a>
  </td>
  <td class="border_test_total">
   <b>${myStatus}</b>
  </td>
  <td class="border_test_total">
   <j:choose>
    <j:when test="${myStatus=='200'}"><img src="${rooturl}userContent/BSGreen.png" width="15px" /></j:when>
    <j:otherwise><img src="${rooturl}userContent/BSRed.png" width="15px" /></j:otherwise>
   </j:choose>
  </td>                     
 </tr>
 </x:forEach>
</table>
```